# What is $e_{ij}Ae_{kl}$ where $e_{xy}$ is the unit matrix with a 1 in row $x$, column $y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have worked out that $Ae_{ij}$ is the $j$th row of $A$, and that $e_{ij}A$ is the $i$th column of $A$. Also, $e_jAe_k$ is the element $a_{jk}$ of A.

$e_{ii}Ae_{jj}$ is the element $a_{ij}$.

Using what I've already shown, we know that $e_{ij}A$ is the $j$th row of A. Now we need to multiply this row vector by by matrix $e_{kl}$. Do we get the $l$th entry in this row? In other words, $a_{lj}$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok just for clearification, for $e_{ij}A = A^\#$ you got:

$$ (A^\#)_{pq} = \sum_{m=1}^n (e_{ij})_{pm}A_{mq} = \left\{\begin{matrix}0 & p\not = i\\ a_{jq} & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right. $$

Then $B=A^\#e_{kl}$: 
$$ B_{pq} = \sum_{m=1}^nA^\#_{pm}(e_{kl})_{mq}=\left\{\begin{matrix}0 & q\not=l\land p\not=i\\ a_{il} & \text{otherwise}\end{matrix} \right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $B_{il}$ isn't $a_{il}$ but $a_{jk}$. Hence 
$$
e_{ij}Ae_{kl}=B=a_{jk}e_{il},
$$
i.e. $e_{ij}Ae_{kl}$ is the matrix whose entry at position (il) is $a_{jk}$ and whose other entries are zero.